# Crashing when adding custom view controllers to UITabBarController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

My iOS 6 application recently started crashing when adding custom view controllers to a UITabBarController.

My AppDelegate has public properties

```
@property (readwrite, strong) UITabBarController *TabBarController;
@property (readwrite, strong) ViewControllerTypeA *ViewControllerA;  //extends UIViewController Class
@property (readwrite, strong) ViewControllerTypeB *ViewControllerB;  //extends UIViewController Class
@property (readwrite, strong) ViewControllerTypeC *ViewControllerC;  //extends UIViewController Class
```

Initially, I create a tab bar controller, and add the view controllers to this:

```
- (void)InitializeTabBar {

[self setTabBarController:[[UITabBarController alloc] init]];
UITabBarItem *Tab1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] init];
UITabBarItem *Tab1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] init];
UITabBarItem *Tab2 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] init];

[self setViewControllerA:[[ViewControllerTypeA alloc] init]];
[self setViewControllerB:[[ViewControllerTypeB alloc] init]];
[self setViewControllerC:[[ViewControllerTypeC alloc] init]];

[[self ViewControllerA] setTabBarItem:Tab1];
[[self ViewControllerB] setTabBarItem:Tab2];
[[self ViewControllerC] setTabBarItem:Tab3];

[[self TabBarController] setViewControllers:@[[self ViewControllerA],[self ViewControllerB],[self ViewControllerC]] animated:NO];

}
```

And it crashes on the last line with error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: ' -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]'

However, if I instead insert default UIViewController Classes, i.e.:

```
[[self TabBarController] setViewControllers:@[[[UIViewController alloc] init],[[UIViewController alloc] init],[[UIViewController alloc] init]] animated:NO];
```

Everything then loads perfectly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try this, NSArray *multipleViewControllers=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[self ViewControllerA],[self ViewControllerB],[self ViewControllerC],nil];
 [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:multipleViewControllers];

Comment: check whether you are doing anything wrong in `viewDidLoad` or `loadView` or `viewWillAppear` method of your custom controller, because your code looks perfect.

Comment: Put the exceptional break point and check where exactly it is crashing.

Comment: Thanks, this appears correct - it is crashing in the viewDidLoad method. The line on which it crashing is the creation of a view controller: "[[[self NavigationController] view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0,-20,ScreenWidth,ScreenHeight - (ControllerHeightOffset+29))];"   Unfortunately this confuses me just as much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, in the end it had to do with using a custom font in the UINavigationBar. Apparently it was trying to initialize the NavController before the font was set - so it crashed as soon as I tried to access the view. Crazy. Thanks for the help all!

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably is that you are trying to insert a nil object into a dictionary, since there are no dictionary around here, it could be something inside the cycle of the first view controller.